# Mask numbers in the credit card

Tags: card.io

I want to mask the numbers of the credit card when the user is taking the picture and leave only the last 4 digits, is it possible?

Thanks, 
Shir

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Is there any particular reason you aren't reaching out for alternatives to [card.io]?

Answer (score 0):

Dave from card.io here.

@ShirA is your desire that the while the card is visible in the camera view, before the scan has even completed, all but the last 4 digits should be obscured?

If you think about it, you'll see that this could never be guaranteed.

The user can hold their card in any orientation and at any distance relative to the camera. Only when the card is in roughly the correct position can card.io even determine where the edges of the card are. And then it will take a moment longer for card.io to locate the card numbers themselves. (In some cases, such as non-traditional cards, it will not be able to locate the numbers at all.)

I can imagine a complete redesign of the camera view in card.io that might satisfy you. For one example, the entire center region of the screen could be obscured at all times, so that only the periphery of the card is ever visible.

But we're not currently in a position to redesign card.io to such a degree.

If this is really important to you, the [card.io codebase is open-source](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-source). You can experiment yourself, and we would be delighted to review a Pull Request with any suggested improvements to card.io.